# how to animate .jpg image with CSS?

Tags: css, animation

I'm trying to animate an image, i.e. to move it from left to right and back but before implementing css animation keyframes i noticed that i cannot get  element in html to obey css style - whatever style changes i make in css, the picture on the webpage remains the same size, in the same place, etc.

html:

```
<div id="animate"><img class="thumbnail" src="flower.jpg"> </div>
```

css:

```
#animate 
{
    width:200x;
    height:100px;
}
```

Comment: well to be honest whatever you typed in html/css is static, meaning once loaded it would be always like that.

want dynamic css "features"? think Javascript.

My advice is to use jQuery to have animation features for your code in this case.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to select the `img`:

```
img {
    width: 200x;
    height: 100px;
}
```

Comment: @One Trick Pony, you mean `#animate img` yes, that would work too.

Comment: best approach is to name this specific img node with an unique id, then select it in css

Comment: thanks, that kind of worked - i selected `#animate img` and for testing purposes made width 500px and height 400px. refreshed page - the image got these dimensions.
thinking that the problem solved i set width and height to previous values, refreshed - but image still remains 500x400. restarted browser - no help. 
btw i removed `class="thumbnail"` from <img> - its a relic from previous code and didnt noticed it before posting

Comment: OK, i think my last comment is not related to the main question raised in this thread, therefore i consider the question answered